# If Condition inside if Condition in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Can't I use if condition inside if. I want to check the second condition if first is pass,

```
 <cc>
    <xsl:variable name="UpperNode" select="(substring-before(//Node1/@SubMan, ' -'))"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($UpperNode,'CUBE')">
        <xsl:if test="not(//CubeNode/@att = 'NORMAL')">
            <ERROR Significiance="U can't draw it" ErrorCode="Sket" ErrorType="Error" Template="Arts.xsd"/>
            <action_on_error>
                <msg_box/>
            </action_on_error>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>   
</cc>
```

It is not popping the message box even though UpperNode is CUBE and CubeNode/@att is NORMAL . How can this type of condition can be check.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It is not giving error but I am not getting expected result

Comment: Please post a complete repro (the input document, a complete and minimal stylesheet that reproduces the problem, the actual output and the expected output).

Comment: But, Let me know whether we can use if inside if

Comment: To answer your basic question, yes you can nest `if` inside `if` in XSLT.

However, from your question, I'm assuming you want the `ERROR` when the UpperNode is CUBE and //CubeNode/@att is NORMAL, but you've wrapped your second `if` test expression in `not()`, meaning it'll only pass through when //CubeNode/@att is anything but NORMAL. Is there a reason for this @Cool_Binami ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are you (in words) trying to test for here: //CubeNode/@att = 'NORMAL' .... I suspect your words will not match this test

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the second test expression: `//CubeNode/&att`.  See the `&`?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected it. But that is not a case.

Comment: Please post a complete repro then, and the error you get.

Comment: It is not giving error but I am not getting expected result

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that shows your question is wrong. Perhaps you will see some solution in this:

Input XML:

```
    <stuff>
        <test1>
            <Node1 SubMan="CUBE - Stuff"/>
            <CubeNode att='NOT NORMAL'/>        
        </test1>
        <test2>
            <Node1 SubMan="CUBE - Stuff"/>
            <CubeNode att='NORMAL'/>   
        </test2>
    </stuff>
```

Test XSL:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       version="1.0">
       <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
           <results>
               <xsl:call-template name="optest">
                   <xsl:with-param name="test" select="//test1"/>
               </xsl:call-template>
               <xsl:call-template name="optest">
                   <xsl:with-param name="test" select="//test2"/>
               </xsl:call-template>
           </results>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template name="optest">
           <xsl:param name="test"/>
           <cc>
               <xsl:variable name="UpperNode" select="(substring-before(//Node1/@SubMan, ' -'))"/>
               <xsl:if test="contains($UpperNode,'CUBE')">
                   <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$test/CubeNode/@att"/></xsl:message>
                   <xsl:if test="not($test/CubeNode/@att[. = 'NORMAL'])">
                       <ERROR Significiance="U can't draw it" ErrorCode="Sket" ErrorType="Error" Template="Arts.xsd"/>
                       <action_on_error>
                           <msg_box/>
                       </action_on_error>
                   </xsl:if>
               </xsl:if>   
           </cc>
       </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<results>
 <cc>
  <ERROR Significiance="U can't draw it" ErrorCode="Sket" ErrorType="Error" Template="Arts.xsd"/>
  <action_on_error>
     <msg_box/>
  </action_on_error>
</cc>
<cc/>
</results
```